# VB.NET milliseconds timer - "hh\:mm\:ss\,fff"

Tags: c#, subtitle

I Need Timer That Counting milliseconds - Explanation:

Format: "hh\:mm\:ss\,fff"

```
If MilliTimer.ForMilliseconds = "00:00:01,447" Then
Label1.text = "Test"
End If
```

(the code is for explanation only)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are asking for, but if you want to test how many milliseconds have transpired since you started a "timer", you want the StopWatch class.  You can start the stop watch like this:

```
StopWatch sw = new stopWatch();
sw.Start();
```

And then you can test how many milliseconds have transpired like this:

```
if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1447)
```

Comment: Yes , i want to check it. you got Example?